# How can I add operator ternary in class on the view laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade, ternary-operator

I try like this :

```
@for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) 
...
    <div class="image ($i==0) ? 'image-main' : ''">
...
@endfor
```

But it does not work.

It seems the way of writing is incorrect.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In laravel's blade file you need to use `{{}}` to execute php code.

```
{{ ($i == 0) ? 'image-main' : '' }}
```

Comment: If you have free time. Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44174515/how-can-i-edit-json-element-by-sub-json-value

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `{{ }}`

```
@for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
    ...
    <div class="image {{ ($i==0) ? 'image-main' : '' }}">
    ...
@endfor
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="{{ ($i == 0) ? 'image-main' : '' }}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this,

```
@for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) 
    <div class="image{{ ($i==0) ? 'image-main' : '' }}">
@endfor
```