# How can I edit json element by sub json value?

Tags: php, json, string

My json like this :

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "xkCT0QUAK7alZkYkbrLUfxoYyn9aXMh2kyCZeYFW.jpeg"}, 
{"id": 2, "name": "9Tg1QLJGiHPC39KP20iOgy3cYQSXOllJTEBGPcF7.jpeg"}, 
{"id": 3, "name": "fWEfhpRkfy44lqC3Ro1etJKmOOkMXnLJLT4ncS6x.png"}]
```

I have input variable `$id`, variable `$name` and variable `$alt`

if `$id = 2`, `$name = 8GJE5LJGiHPC39KP20iOgy3cYQSXOllJTE7G84D2.jpeg`,  and `$alt = test one`, it will edit json that have `id = 2` to be like this :

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "xkCT0QUAK7alZkYkbrLUfxoYyn9aXMh2kyCZeYFW.jpeg"}, 
{"id": 2, "name": "8GJE5LJGiHPC39KP20iOgy3cYQSXOllJTE7G84D2.jpeg", "alt": "test one"}, 
{"id": 3, "name": "fWEfhpRkfy44lqC3Ro1etJKmOOkMXnLJLT4ncS6x.png"}]
```

if `$id = 3`, `$name = 33AABBCCEDC39KP20iOgy3cYQSXOllJaaBBCCE3.jpeg` and `$alt = test two`, it will edit json that have `id = 3`like this :

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "xkCT0QUAK7alZkYkbrLUfxoYyn9aXMh2kyCZeYFW.jpeg"}, 
{"id": 2, "name": "9Tg1QLJGiHPC39KP20iOgy3cYQSXOllJTEBGPcF7.jpeg"}, 
{"id": 3, "name": "33AABBCCEDC39KP20iOgy3cYQSXOllJaaBBCCE3.png", "alt": "test two"}]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just find by id then change it. Check live [demo here](https://eval.in/805022).

```
<?php
$array = json_decode('[{"id": 1, "name": "xkCT0QUAK7alZkYkbrLUfxoYyn9aXMh2kyCZeYFW.jpeg"}, 
{"id": 2, "name": "9Tg1QLJGiHPC39KP20iOgy3cYQSXOllJTEBGPcF7.jpeg"}, 
{"id": 3, "name": "fWEfhpRkfy44lqC3Ro1etJKmOOkMXnLJLT4ncS6x.png"}]');

$id = 2;
$name = '8GJE5LJGiHPC39KP20iOgy3cYQSXOllJTE7G84D2.jpeg';
$alt = 'test one';
foreach($array as &$v)
{
  if($v->id == $id){
    $v->alt = $alt;
    $v->name = $name;
  }
}
print_r(json_encode($array));
```

When you have a large array, you can use this [efficient way](https://eval.in/805019)

```
<?php
$array = json_decode('[{"id": 1, "name": "xkCT0QUAK7alZkYkbrLUfxoYyn9aXMh2kyCZeYFW.jpeg"}, 
{"id": 2, "name": "9Tg1QLJGiHPC39KP20iOgy3cYQSXOllJTEBGPcF7.jpeg"}, 
{"id": 3, "name": "fWEfhpRkfy44lqC3Ro1etJKmOOkMXnLJLT4ncS6x.png"}]');

$id = 2;
$name = '8GJE5LJGiHPC39KP20iOgy3cYQSXOllJTE7G84D2.jpeg';
$alt = 'test one';

$array = array_combine(array_column($array, 'id'), $array);
if(isset($array[$id]))
{
  $array[$id]->name = $name;
  $array[$id]->alt = $alt;
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: It seems that your first code did not update the name. If the second code, it works

Comment: `$v-name = $name;`. Should : `$v->name = $name;`

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help

Comment: glad it helps here

Comment: I need you help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612406/why-ksort-does-not-work-php